# GitPython pulls back the wrong branch names

Tags: git, python-2.7

I am using GitPython to inspect my local repository. When I view the output of `repo.branches`, it shows me different branches then what my current config file holds.

```
location = 'D:\Projects\Atlas\ '
repo = git.Repo(location)
```

Isn't the Git repo looking at the config file on the declared path?

Comment: Wait, what are you doing with Git and Python again?  Are you running Git *through* Python?

Comment: Yes - i am running git bash through python and i want to connect to my local repository.

Comment: So you're using Git bash, and the files you want to store in Git are Python files then?  Or are you trying to programatically trying to access your Git repo through Python?  Be clear here; I don't know if you're using Git bash and want to do stuff on the command line, or if you're writing a Python program to do stuff through Git.

Comment: i'll try to be more clear.
i'm using pycharm and i imported git into my working area and when i am trying to connect to my local repository i see that when i print the content of the repository it gives the wrong branches

Comment: @ArielEinfeld, maybe you could walk us through an example of what you'd like to do.

Comment: Okay - so you're using [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) then.  You're attempting to do this programatically.  Alright, I've got some ideas as to where you're going with this.

Comment: would be happy to: 
1. using pycharm on a new project "import git" 
2. connecting to my local repository repo = git.Repo('D:\Projects\Atlas\ ') 
3. printing repo.branches
output are wrong branches then what i have in my .git/config file in my repository

i want to have the ability to view my .git/config file which holds the branches i have connected to, but the problem is that i suspect its not showing me the .git/config file

Comment: Would you show us the output of `repo.branches` vs `git branch`?  Why are you saying that they're different?  Are you sure that in `Atlas\` there's a .git folder?

Comment: repo.branches returns feature/SCRUM-577-aerospike-userstore
feature/roadmap-947-adv_project_ab_testing
feature/rtb-server
master
refs/heads/release
release/atlas-0.9.3
release/atlas-1.1.1

git branch returns:
feature/SCRUM-577-aerospike-userstore
feature/roadmap-947-adv_project_ab_testing
feature/rtb-server
master
refs/heads/release
release/atlas-0.9.3
release/atlas-1.1.1

Comment: ...Can you **edit that into the question**?  Comments are not the medium for that sort of information.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the problem myself - it didnt had to do with anything but a glitch.

i have 2 local repository and when i tried to do the same thing on the other repository all worked as expected and i got the list of branch.
that got me to think that there is an error on my other repository and then i remember that a few days ago i got an error message regarding a gitlock file.
so it must have done something to my system.

so i deleted my repository and clone it again and now it works.
thanks for all of you who tried to help!